# How to load a javascript library that is not in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Here is the official document covering the [module loading in Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). A section titled "Ambient Modules" is talking about loading module that is not written in Typescript. I am trying to do simple learning project to use the method explained in the official document to load a module.

I am trying to use Typescript to load this following MyThing.js library.

```
// myThings.js
function getMyThing (){
    return "This is my thing";
}

function getMyObject() {
    return {
        a: 1,
        b: "my object"
    }
}
```

Here is my myThing.d.ts file:

```
// myThing.d.ts
declare module myThing {
    interface MyObject {
        a: number;
        b: string;
    }

    export function getMyThing():string;
    export function getMyObject():MyObject;

}
```

Here is the app.ts that use the myThing library.

```
// app.ts
import {getMyThing} from "./myThing.d";
```

myThing.js, myThing.d.ts, and app.ts are in the same folder. Oh boy, nothing is right. 
When I compile app.ts, got the following error:

```
myThing.d.ts' is not a module. (2306)
```

My question is how do I import a module that is not written in Typescript? Do I have to use declare file? Please provide sample code using the demo files above.

I've already read the official document, but still couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

### Exporting the type definition module

When Typescript tries to import your module, it looks in the relevant file (in this case, `myThing.d.ts`, and sees if a module with that name (`getMyThing`) is exported. In this case, you merely declared a module, but did not export it, so you want to change your `.d.ts` file to the following:

```
// myThing.d.ts
export module myThing {
//^ we changed from 'declare' to 'export'
    interface MyObject {
        a: number;
        b: string;
    }
    export function getMyThing():string;
    export function getMyObject():
}
```

### Importing the module correctly

Now, when you compile, you will get the following error:

```
app.ts(1,9): error TS2305: Module '"/home/gnalck/workspace/modules/myThing"' has no exported member 'getMyThing'.
```

This is because you exported one logical module `myThing`, and nothing more. As such, change your import statement to the following:

```
import {myThing} from './myThing';
```

If you want to still use `getMyThing`, you would reference it as `myThing.getMyThing()`.

### Updating the JS file to be modular

With these changes, if you run it in e.g., node, you will still get a runtime error, like the following: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMyThing' of undefined`. This is because your JS file is not modular.

You need to format your JS file to have a similar export topography as your `.d.ts` file. Here is one solution, using CommonJS style:

```
module.exports = {
  myThing: {
    getMyThing: function () {
      return "This is my thing";
    },

    getMyObject: function () {
      return {
        a: 1,
        b: "my object"
      }
    }
  }
}
```