# In Typescript, how to consume a javascript lib that provides global variable?

Tags: typescript

I am strictly following the example in the [official guide for declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables).

Global library

```
// foo.js
foo = 20;
```

declaration file

```
// foo.d.ts
declare const let foo: number;
```

consuming the declaration file and library

```
// app.ts
/// <reference path="./foo.d.ts" />
console.log(foo);
```

The error message is:

> Cannot find name 'foo'. (2304)

I've asked the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671963/how-to-load-a-javascript-library-that-is-not-in-typescript/39672124#39672124), but problem not solved. 
I know the theory and read the official guide already. But official guide tell you how to write declaration file, but failed to provide example on how to import the declared file.

Can you help me edit the code to make the above example work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your declaration file uses invalid syntax. If `foo` is meant to be used as a readonly variable use this syntax:

```
declare const foo: number;
```

Comment: doesn't work. when I compile app.ts, the error message is " foo is not defined"

Comment: I think the problem is in the app.ts. Did I import it correctly?

Comment: Yes that kind of import should work. Both files should be on the same directory. As a side note, you should rename foo.ts to something else because the generated foo.js will overwrite yours.

Comment: I changed the foo.js to fooGlobal.js, it doesn't work. "foo is not defined"